# Object prototype is copied or referenced in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, javascript-objects

In the following code :

```
let user = {
  name: "John",
  surname: "Smith",

  set fullName(value) {
    [this.name, this.surname] = value.split(" ");
  },

  get fullName() {
    return `${this.name} ${this.surname}`;
  }
};

let admin = {
  __proto__: user,
  isAdmin: true
};

alert(admin.fullName); // John Smith (*)

// setter triggers!
admin.fullName = "Alice Cooper"; // (**)

alert(admin.fullName); // Alice Cooper, state of admin modified
alert(user.fullName); // John Smith, state of user protected
```

The user Object is the prototype of admin Object,
As we see line (**) sets the fullName for admin Object, although user Object remains the way it was.

So is it correct to say that user Properties & Methods are **copied** to admin Object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` reveals that by using `admin.fullName = "Alice Cooper"` you actually create new properties instead of overriding anything.

```js
let user = {
  name: "John",
  surname: "Smith",

  set fullName(value) {
    [this.name, this.surname] = value.split(" ");
  },

  get fullName() {
    return `${this.name} ${this.surname}`;
  }
};

let admin = {
  __proto__: user,
  isAdmin: true
};

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(admin));
admin.fullName = "Alice Cooper";

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(admin));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(user));
```

Changing the the properties of the prototype reveals that it's references

```js
let user = {
  name: "John",
  surname: "Smith",

  set fullName(value) {
    [this.name, this.surname] = value.split(" ");
  },

  get fullName() {
    return `${this.name} ${this.surname}`;
  }
};

let admin = {
  __proto__: user,
  isAdmin: true
};

console.log(admin);
user.fullName = "Alice Cooper";

console.log(admin);
console.log(user);
```

Comment: Agh Got it now, Thanks Mate ! :)